# How to reset permission of geolocation in wkwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, wkwebview

If once user didn't allow location to specific site in `WKWebview` and again user open same website then `WKWebview` will not take permission of geolocation access.How will I do it so that `WKWebview` ask every time for permission of **geolocation** irrespective of how many times user denied it for same site.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If its your website in the webview then you do not ask for the location in the webpage.  Instead you have your viewcontroller get the location from the phone and then you inject the location into your webview via javascript with [evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript).  This prevents the webpage from ever triggering the permission location popup.

Comment: Yes, I can also inject javascript , but I want to do without it. I want to take permission from WKWebview for website everytime irrespective of if it is decline earlier.What was happening is that , WKWebview not asking permission if you decline twice. Is WKWebview save user response to cache .How can I reset it?. Please help